# How to force Kindle Cloud reader to update highlights and notes?

Tags: kindle-cloud-reader

When I update a highlight on my kindle and Sync and then sync the Kindle Cloud Reader page (and sync within it), the highlight can take still take 10 or 20 minutes to show up.

Is there any way to speed this up?